# How to define two or more values with only one #define?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

For example, something like:

```
    #define{
        VAR1 53
        VAR2 71
        etc.
    }
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: No, it's not possible

Comment: Why would you not want to use more than one `#define`?

Comment: Why don't you use a constant array?

Comment: But constant array and enums are not preprocessed.. (?)

Comment: enums are preprocessed. A enum type is basically an `int` that the compiler will check if you are trying to set to a predefined value at compile time, but at run time no check is made and its not impairing at all. You can safely assume enums are #defines that only accept numbers.

Comment: What would you need a "preprocessed enum" for? And no @Havenard, enums are not preprocessed in the sense that their values would be "preprocessing time constants" (which might or might not be what the OP needs)

Comment: You aren't making any sense. enums do are preprocessed, they are not any sort of array or constant structure that remains in the binaries. The enum elements don't have a memory address, they can't be changed at run time, and they are for all effects, preprocessed.

Comment: @Havenard "preprocessed" implies being part of the C preprocessor, which enums are not. You could really describe the whole compilation process as preprocessing, but that's confusing.

Comment: But thats exactly what it is.

Comment: @Havenard Preprocessing is defined in the standard as phases 3 and 4 of translation; it is often extended to include phases 1-6, but using the term for anything beyond that just leads to confusion.  (Phases 7 and 8 are compiling, phase 9 linking, in traditional terminology.)  `enum` is _not_ a keyword for the preprocessor, and the values of enumeration constants are _not_ known to the preprocessor.  E.g. after `enum X { a = 42 };`, `#if a == 0` will evaluate as true, not false.

Comment: Its a mere detail. What I said is still correct, they are not variables, they can't be addressed, they cant be changed at run time, they are not validated against any set of values at run time, for all effects they are constant values just like `#define` but that only take integers. And I am 100% sure of what I'm saying because I deal with disassembling and software reversing, I know exactly how those things end up in the binaries.

Comment: @Havenard: No, what you said is not correct. If you are using terms such as "preprocessed" to describe things that, by definition, are _not_ "preprocessed" in any way at all (and it seems that you are), then your 100% certainty in your job is rather alarming. Please inform me which tools you create, so that I may avoid them.

Comment: @Havenard: What you mean to say is that `enum` types exist only at compilation-time and do not exist in any form in the resulting compiled binary. Well, frankly, this is true of _all_ types — all that remains in the binary is the _data_ and the code that knows how to read it.

Answer (score 2):

The `#define`-clause is a command to the preprocessor who does *textual* replacements to your sourcecode before it is passed to the compiler. The syntax for `#define` is

```
#define VALUE TEXT_TO_REPLACE_VALUE
```

That's about it. There might some ways to conditionally create expressions, but not in a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enum`, for exemple:

```
enum Gender
{
    GENDER_UNKNOWN = 0,
    GENDER_MALE    = 1,
    GENDER_FEMALE  = 2
};
```

You can then declare variables of type `Gender` in C++ or `enum Gender` in C, that should only accept one of its elements as value, otherwise the compiler will throw a Warning.

But `enum` does not accept any declaration as `#define` does, you can basically only use it with integers.

Comment: First, `enum` also exists in C. Then, defining an enum is not exactly the same as defining a constant with the preprocessor's `#define` (a preprocessor defined constant can be checked by some `#ifdef` etc and nothing tells us if the OP would need such features or not).
Anyway, an enum is elegant to handle customized error codes (for example) :)

Comment: When assigning to a variable of type `Gender`, the right hand side of the assignment must have type `Gender` (at least in C++).  Otherwise, the code shouldn't compile.  But all it takes is a `static_cast` to make pretty much any integer a `Gender`.

Comment: Yes, put in practice its an `int` that the compiler will attempt to impose use restrictions, but naturally playing with pointers and type casts you can give it whatever value you want, just like with any other type in the language.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array for VAR, and declare as much valuable as u want.
then you can enter the values like this, an example is below

Example: I want to store 5 values into VAR

```
int VAR[5];
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    scanf("%d", &VAR[i]);
    }
```